# Can't tell when code inside Meteor.defer has finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, integration-testing

I'm writing integration tests for my meteor project. I want to test the webhook POST handler in my app. This is how it looks like:

```
post() {
  Meteor.defer(() => {
    // some logic here, e.g insert / update database
  })
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
  }
}
```

**Note:** `Meteor.defer` is a must because I want to return code 200 (OK) as soon as possible.
To test this webhook, I create a fake POST request to this webhook, then check if the database is updated accordingly. The thing is that in the test I don't know when the code inside `Meteor.defer` has finished, therefore my assertions are failed because the database hasn't been updated yet.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround: using Mocha's test [timeouts](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts) to wait for a specific amount of time before doing assertions. It's not the best solution but it works at the moment.